# how can i call python code from pyqt like the below c code?os.system('./txt+str(self.fname))

Tags: python, pyqt

```
import sys,time,os
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import random,string
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PIL import Image


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

        def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

        def initUI(self):  
        self.label1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)   
        self.label2 = QtGui.QLabel(self) 
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Browse', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        self.button.move(250,65)

        self.button2=QtGui.QPushButton('Scrambled',self)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.s)
        self.button2.move(90,650)
        self.resize(800, 500)
        self.button3 = QtGui.QPushButton('Descrambled', self)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.de)
        self.button3.move(1000,650)


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1500, 1500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Select Image')
        self.le = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
            self.le.move(90, 65)
        self.show()



        def showDialog(self):
        self.fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 
                '/home/merin/mainprj/1')
        print '**********************'

        self.le.setText(str(self.fname))
        self.hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        myPixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.fname)
        self.label1.setPixmap(myPixmap)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.label1)
            self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.move(1500,150)


        def s(self):
        os.system('$python scramble.py'+str(self.fname))
        myPixmap2 = QtGui.QPixmap(self.fname)
        print type(self.fname)      
        self.label2.setPixmap(myPixmap2)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.label2)
            self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.move(1500,150)


        def de(self):
        os.system('$python scramble.py '+str(self.fname))
        myPixmap2 = QtGui.QPixmap(self.fname)
        print type(self.fname)      
        self.label2.setPixmap(myPixmap2)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.label2)
            self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.move(1500,150)



def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I call python code from pyqt like the below c code?

```
os.system('./txt+str(self.fname))
```

Comment: That isn't C code. That looks like Python code, except for the string that isn't terminated.

Answer (score 0):

exec/eval or make an interpreter and send text through the interpreter.

Note: these are not safe operations and can leave vulnerabilities within your code.

```py
exec("some code")
```

or

use ast literal eval which is safer.

```
import ast

ast.literal_eval("somecode")
```

To make a python interpreter https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/code.html. You will also want to look up